# Yet another simple math problem

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking

There seems to be a trend lately for simple math problems. So here is my version. It's super simple:

$23 + 62 = 94$
$41 + 22 = 36$
$10 + 20 = 21$
$50 + 17 = 22$
$67 + 96 = 172$

Problem:

> $99 + 99 = x$

What is the value of $x$?

Comment: it is 198. All your above additions are wrong. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is

> 198

Explanation

> 23+62=94. // (6+3)(2+2)
>      41+22=36 // (2+1)(4+2)
>      67+96=172 //(9+7)(6+6) =16(12)
>                       // carrying one gives us 172

Similarly

> 99+99=198

Comment: when I did arithmetic (6+3)(2+2) = 36 not 94

Comment: also you have not explained 50+17

Comment: (0+1)(5+7)=1(12) carry one gives 22

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way to look at this is

> Reverse the first number then add to the second

I know this is the same as the other answers, but it explains the

> 99+99 case much better than (9+9)(9+9) which should be 1818.

Comment: This also explains `50 +17` better than the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

> 198.

The reason is:

> The first number is the sum of the second number and of the third one. The second number is the sum of the first number and of the last number.
>  For instance, for the first one, we have 23 + 62 = (3 + 6) and (2+2) = 94. In the case of 67+96=172, you had 67+96=(7+9)(6+6)=(16)(12). In such case, you summed the second number of the left member with the first member of the right one, giving here (16)(12) = (1)(6+1)(2) = 172.
>  So for the last one, we have 99 + 99 = (9+9)(9+9)=(18)(18)=(1)(8+1)(8)=198.

Comment: I'm in a dilemma right now. Both you and @rudra answered the question at almost the same time. But rudra is 7 seconds faster so I think I'll accept his. Good job anyways!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Ah ah. That's what I get for trying to put the reason earlier :p